# Как получить граф сущностей удаляемых каскадом?

Tags: java, hibernate

Задумал я пользователю, удаляющему какую-либо сущность, показывать страничку подтверждения удаления, на которой будет отображаться иерархия всех удаляемых каскадом сущностей. Вроде такого:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
И уже начал прикидывать, как это лучше реализовать, но у меня возникло острое чувство велосипедостроения. Наверняка я не первый, кто такое делает. Уверен, даже не в первой тысяче. Вот только Google готовых решений мне не подсказал. Знает кто-нибудь об уже существующих способах решения этой задачи? Если таких нет, было бы интересно обсудить красивые и эффективные варианты.

Comment: Это у вас веб или десктопное ПО?

Comment: @GardenMan сейчас web, но может быть и EJB, например. Разве это существенно?

Comment: Просто хотел узнать связан ли вопрос с UI или внутренней реализацией

Comment: @GardenMan идеальный вариант - остаться в рамках JPA. В крайнем случае в пределах модели.

Comment: Скорее всего, придется собирать аннотации по пакету (повторяя работу Hibernate) и строить рекурсивно запросы.

Comment: @VictorKhovanskiy если я всё-таки первый в этом, то точно заимею наконец на гитхабе репу с кучей звёздочек :)

Comment: можно, вроде, у Hibernate [спросить](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26925359) метаданные

Comment: @zRrr спасибо! Пригодится, если возьмусь сам писать "графопостраитель".

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете нарисовать такую структуру используя Reflection API:

1. взять сущность, получить список полей
2. сделать поле доступным (на случай, если оно приватное)
3. вернуть значение поля, а если это объект или массив, то провалится внутрь и начать с п.1

Возможно, алгоритм, изложенный в файле https://github.com/hawkab/redmine_integration/blob/master/src/main/java/ru/hawkab/redmineintegration/util/InterpolateUtil.java

в методе `getMapByObject` вам поможет в формировании целевой структуры.

Comment: Ага, могу. И даже на скорую руку накидал в том проекте, который этот вопрос породил. Но неужели никто ещё не реализовал готового решения для этого класса задач? Честно говоря, столь полезный функционал я ожидал увидеть в Hibernate из коробки и удивлён тем, что его там нет.

Comment: В Hibernate много чего нет. Недавно сталкивался с тем, что Hibernate.Envers не умеет создавать ревизию вручную, а делает это только по событию изменения сущности.

Answer (score 0):

если загрузить дерево через JPA EntityGraph не целесообразно (например потому что придется "вручную" задавать субструктуры, которые нас интересуют) то
можно попробовать хакерский способ:

1. конфигурация:

- транзакции управляются программно (не контейнером)
- установлен перехватчик события удаления, например PreDeleteEventListener (см. https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-event-listeners/)
- или hibernate Interceptor (удобно унаследоваться от EmptyInterceptor)
- альтернативно JPA/Hibernate перехватчикам, можно врезать перехватчик на уровне JDBC драйвера и отлавливать DELETE команды (но это на любителя (или "тру хакера", который пишет код на java исключительно через echo :) )); преимуществом такого способа будет надежность и универсальность, недостатком - отсутствие информации о сущностях, будут только таблицы.

2. начать транзакцию
3. выполнить удаление
4. возможно придется вызвать flush()
5. собрать список / дерево сущностей из событий полученных перехватчиком
6. далее по ситуации

- вариант А: откатить транзакцию и показать диалог
- вариант Б: (если позволяют настройки БД) оставить транзакцию в подвешенном состоянии и закоммитить когда пользователь подтвердит удаление.

Answer (score -2):

Насчет готовых решений я не уверен, но однако ваша ситуация мне напомнила один маленький проект который я реализовал очень давно. Надо было рисовать иерархию файловой системы в виде дерево как у вас. Только я его делал на десктопном приложении. Вот пример кода:

```
package dir.hierarchy;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class FileUtil {

    public static void main(String[] a) throws IOException {
        String path = "/opt/apache-maven-3.5.0";
        showDir(1, new File(path));
    }

    private static void showDir(int indent, File file) throws IOException {

        for (int i = 0; i < indent; i++)
            System.out.print('-');

        System.out.println(file.getName());

        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            File[] files = file.listFiles();
            if (files != null) {
                for (File file1 : files)
                    showDir(indent + 4, file1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Пример кода взят [отсюда](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/File-Input-Output/ReadingandPrintingaDirectoryHierarchy.htm). Вот что он печатает.

```
-apache-maven-3.5.0
-----bin
---------m2.conf
---------mvn
---------mvn.cmd
---------mvnDebug
---------mvnDebug.cmd
---------mvnyjp
-----boot
---------plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar
-----conf
---------logging
-------------simplelogger.properties
---------settings.xml
---------toolchains.xml
-----lib
...
```

Тут точно такой же принцип, просто Вам надо будет заменить файловую систему на систему категорий. Вам надо будет создать таблицу категорий в БД, показывая отношения родитель-ребенок. Вообщем общая картинка выглядит так.

Comment: Э нет, ORM - это не файловая система. Мне надо определить отношения между моделями, у которых назначен каскад и построить ациклический граф по ним. При этом не порвать базу запросами и не заблокировать на продолжительный срок. А так же крайне желательно сделать всё это быстро, но потокобезопасно. К тому же, мне как раз нужен обобщённый алгоритм, который сможет прожевать любую модель, какую бы я ему не сунул. Это может быть и не _категория_. У модели может быть неопределённое количество отношений неопределённого уровня вложенности.

Comment: Мда, я не обратил внимание на ациклический граф. Задача и вправду очень интересная.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev А что если топовая категория является под категорией из нижней грани. То в этом случае если вы будете удалить нижнюю грань то удалится вся категория. Как быть в этой ситуации?

Comment: Удалять будет Hibernate, который умеет этот граф строить или делегировать эту задачу СУБД . А мне надо только отобразить его, либо вытащив как-то из Hibernate без удаления, либо построив самостоятельно.